# How to filter product based on specific arrribute in magento and call via cms page as well from controller

Tags: magento

I need some tips to use product list functionality in my cms pages.

like in my cms page named "manufacture = apple" should show all products of apple manufacture .

same for other attribute like color, size etc .....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create small module. I can't share complete code here, but sharing you a helpful link which I have earlier used and working fine.

Link:https://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/

Hope it will helpful!

Answer (score 1):

create a template (test.phtml) under yourtheme/catalog/product and add the following code to your test.phtml

```
<?php
  $arrParams = array_slice($this->getRequest()->getParams(),1);
  $attribute = each($arrParams);
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($attribute[0],$attribute[1]);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($collection->getData());
  exit;
?>
```

than call this template to your cms page. Add the code below in content area of your cms page.

```
{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/test.phtml"}}
```

once you have the array of product than display it as per your requirement.